# Is there a possibility to generate sitemap.xml in SPA React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, generator, sitemap

I have SPA in React 18.2.0 and I want to generate sitemap.xml. I have tried the React Router Sitemap package and it does not work with the latest version of React. I also want it to generate all subpages according to my routes.js file.

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/sortiment",
    component: Sortiment
  },
  {
    path: "/kontakt",
    component: Contact
  },
  {
    path: "/aktualne",
    component: News
  },
  {
    path: "/o-nas",
    component: About
  },
  {
    path: "/nase-sluzby",
    component: Services
  },
  {
    path: "/sortiment/:categoryName",
    component: CategoryPage
  },
];
```

I also tried installing React Router Sitemap Generator and the result was the same.

Comment: No, React has no concept of a sitemap.  It has no concept of "routing" in this sense at all by itself, which is literally why packages like react-router exist.

Comment: just create a file called sitemap.xml, or use [this tool](https://github.com/DeanVanGreunen/xdspider) that I created for generating sitemap xml files, its free, its open source, just point it at your site and it will search and create, only issue is that it access the raw html, it does no rendering of html/js, so if you want you can extend this and then add that, so it can process the reactjs